# How to propagate user defined build settings in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build

My X-code project has 3 targets, each generates an app.
It also has a nested project, which every target is dependent on. The nested project has a build phase that generates some code from a plist. (The step must be in the nested project since it generates code that is later compiled in the main project).
The plist file name is different between the 3 targets and it is defined per target in the build settings as a user defined build settings.

I want to be able to call

`generateSomeCode.sh ${PROJECT_ROOT}/${ConfigurationFile}.plist`

In a way that `ConfigurationFile` is defined in the main target, while its beeing read from the nested project's build phase.